# Google Cloud shell appears to be hanging on provisioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Anyone else having issues with Cloud Shell this morning? -- My first time working in GCP and when I clicked on cloud shell, the process appears to be hanging at the provisioning stage. According to the docs, this should only take a minute, but I've been waiting more than 20 minutes now and it's still spinning with no apparent progress.

I thought it might have been blocking some process (thank you uBlock origin), but reloading the page with uBlock turned off, I see the same behavior.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you been disconnected (from your Google account) and try to reconnect afterward to Cloud Shell?

Comment: Did you try another browser? To me it helped switching from Firefox to Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is hard to investigate/track since no error appeared, sometimes related to Cloud Shell location/region. I may suggest to troubleshoot by doing any steps below:

1. In the Cloud Shell menu, click the three dots menu icon, then click Restart Cloud Shell. Click Restart Cloud Shell in the confirmation dialog.
2. Add the following in the address bar in Cloud Shell URL so it will open the shell in the safe mode then click the three dots menu icon and click Restart.

- `&cloudshellsafemode=true`

3. Try to restart the browser or you can try to access or open the Cloud Shell with a different browser.
4. Try the browser incognito mode.

If the Cloud Shell still does not open, as a workaround, I recommend to install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) to your machine to access your GCP resources.

If all the steps above doesn't work, I'll recommend to contact Google Cloud Platform Support or create a [Public Tracker Issue](https://status.cloud.google.com/) to further investigate this kind of issue.