# Why am I getting "Error in getting cloud shell"?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Cloud Shell is experiencing some issues provisioning a VM to you. Please try again in a few minutes.

Comment: I think that the text of your question answers the question?

Comment: Try the troubleshooting steps in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64231736/8753991)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/), there's a service interruption incident occurred **globally** which is unable to connect to Cloud Shell from Mar 08, 2021 12:01 US/Pacific time until Mar 08, 2021 12:55.

Based on the [record](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/21004), it's already fixed now and you can use it without any problem.